# Laravel 5.1 Trying to post data to controller but geting MethodNotAllowedHttpException error

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

Im trying to `POST` data to my controller but I'm getting a

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:`

error message, here are my files.

my route file

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Authentication routes
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes
Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
Route::controllers(['password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

// Using A Route Closure
Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function() {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
    Route::auth();
}]);

// practicing using forms for sending data to the DB & populating form fields with DB data
Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@index');
Route::post('profile/update', 'ProfileController@updateProfile');
```

profile.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile/update/">
    <div class="form-group hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $users[0]->id;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email"><b>Name:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your email here" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email"><b>Email:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email here" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Submit </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

& my ProfileController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update user profile & make backend push to DB
    **/

    public function index()
    {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            // connecting to the DB and accessing
            $users = User::all();
            //var_dump($users);

            return view('profile', compact('users'));
        }

        return view('auth/login');
    }

    public function updateProfile(Requests $request) {

        return $request->all();

    }
}
```

not sure what the issue is. Thanks for all the help everyone

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu updated my question

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu im jsut trying to `POST` read somewhere that i needed to add `PATCH` ?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu ive updated my routes to `route::patch` but the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues that we managed to address here:

**Over-use of HTTP Verbs**

At your view, you have: `<form method="POST"` but also `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">` which may conflict between a `POST` and a `PATCH`. Since your `routes.php` only declares `POST`, let's remove the `patch` definition.

**Routing Mistake**

Still at your view, your action points to `action="/profile/update/"` while your route is defined as `Route::post('profile/update')`, notice the extra `/` at the end in your form. That slash should not be there.

**Controllers Request**

You have a here: `use App\Http\Requests;` is probably incorrect because that's a folder within Laravel, not a class. Let's remove that and keep `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` for now. In the near future, you'll be learning how to create your own Form Requests and you'll probably want a `UpdateProfileRequest.php`.